# Insertion in ManyToMany table using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following structs in gorm

```
type Resource struct {
    ID       int          `gorm:"type:INTEGER;primarykey"`
    Name     string       `gorm:"type:VARCHAR(255);NOT NULL"`
    Type     ResourceType `gorm:"NOT NULL"`
    Scopes   []Scope      `gorm:"many2many:resource_scopes"`
    TenantID string       `gorm:"type:VARCHAR(255);NOT NULL"`
}

type Scope struct {
    ID       int    `gorm:"type:INTEGER;primarykey"`
    Name     string `gorm:"type:VARCHAR(255);NOT NULL"`
    TenantID string `gorm:"type:VARCHAR(255);NOT NULL"`
}
```

`ResourceScope` has the foreign keys of Resource and Scope

```
type ResourceScope struct {
    ResourceID int `gorm:"type:INTEGER;primarykey"`
    ScopeID    int `gorm:"type:INTEGER;primarykey"`
    Resource   Resource
    Scope      Scope
}
```

I need to insert the mapping information in my mapping table which is `ResourceScope`. I have the information of Resource and Scope (not their Ids). How can I insert a new row (Ids of Resource and Scope) using the Resource and Scope table information in `ResourceScope` table using gorm.

One solution that is quite easily do-able is to get the resource_id and scope_id Ids first and then insert these ids into ResourceScope. But it will end up with three different queries which is not desirable solution. Please let me know if needed any further demonstration. I tried with the following solution:

```golang
resourceScope := ResourceScope{Resource: Resource{Name: scopeAssignment.Resource, TenantID: scopeAssignment.TenantId}, Scope: scopes[0]}
        result := tx.Omit(clause.Associations).Create(&resourceScope)
```

but it throws the below error (here the resource_id and scope_id is (0,0)):
`"fields": {"error":"ERROR: insert or update on table \"resource_scopes\" violates foreign key constraint \"resource-scope_resource-id_fkey\" (SQLSTATE 23503)","rowsAffected":0,"sql":"INSERT INTO \"authz\".\"resource_scopes\" (\"resource_id\",\"scope_id\") VALUES (0,0)","timeElapsed":"8.897943ms"}}.`

I was expecting it to insert the ids of Resource and Scope in ResourceScope table. But it's inserting (0,0) which throws foreign key constraint error.